# NDesk.Options - detect invalid arguments

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

I am using [NDesk.Options](http://www.ndesk.org/Options) to parse command line arguments for a C# command line program.  It is working fine, except I want my program to exit unsuccessfully, and show the help output, if the user includes arguments that I did not expect.

I am parsing options thusly:

```
var options = new OptionSet {
    { "r|reset",  "do a reset", r => _reset = r != null },
    { "f|filter=",  "add a filter", f => _filter = f },
    { "h|?|help",  "show this message and exit",  v => _showHelp = v != null },
};

try
{
    options.Parse(args);
}
catch (OptionException)
{
    _showHelp = true;
    return false;
}
return true;
```

With this code, if I use an argument improperly, such as specifying `--filter` without  `=myfilter` after it then NDesk.Options will throw an OptionException and everything will be fine.  However, I also expected an OptionException to be thrown if I pass in an argument that doesn't match my list, such as `--someOtherArg`.  But this does not happen.  The parser just ignores that and keeps on trucking.

Is there a way to detect unexpected args with NDesk.Options?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `OptionSet.Parse` method returns the unrecognized options in a `List<string>`. You can use that to report unknown options.

```
try
{
    var unrecognized = options.Parse(args);
    if (unrecognized.Any())
    {
        foreach (var item in unrecognized) 
            Console.WriteLine("unrecognized option: {0}", item);
        _showHelp = true;
        return false;
    }
}
catch (OptionException)
{
    _showHelp = true;
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Comment: That's the key piece I was missing.  Thanks!